# Select cells in a Word Table, that have specific chars

Tags: vba, ms-word

I know this is going to sound like it's been asked and answered but whenever I search for terms, it brings up tips that are not what I'm looking for.

Background: I have a Word document, that has tables and text.  In many of the tables, there are cells that have some comments surrounded by [], or {}, or some terminator.  I need to run a macro, to select/highlight all the cells with those texts and terminators, but only in tables.  After the macro is run, the table will have all cells selected where those terminators exist, as a pair.

Then, I'd like to run the macro again, but this time, delete every such occurance, including the terminators.  I need both macro examples because I'm not sure yet, if I want to review them first, or just delete them. ;)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can single out text contained in tables.

Dim Table As Table, Rng As Range

For Each Table in ActiveDocument.Tables: 
Set Rng = Table.Range

You can search for [] and {} in each range and do your modifications. Post your code here with specific questions if you need help with that.

Comment: That's not answering my question. The 2nd paragraph pretty much says clearly what I want to do, and at the end have cells selected, that have the square brackets or cruly brackets in the cell.

Comment: If you want people to do what you want you will have to pay them. On this site you receive help, and it costs you nothing. It is offered on the understanding that you will do the work yourself.